# Can you reverse a queue by only reversing its head and tail pointers?

Tags: data-structures, queue, big-o, theory

While attempting to reverse a queue, I found a generally agreed upon way:

*You can dequeue through the queue, getting the dequeue value and pushing each one into a stack. Then you can go through that stack, popping each value and enqueueing it into the queue*

By agreed upon, I mean most of my Google searches on reversing a queue end up taking me to that solution.

Even though that way is correct and relatively performant in linear time, I believe there's a better way that is simpler and more performant in constant time.

Assuming that a queue is implemented using a doubly-linked list, can't you reverse it in O(1) time by just *reversing the head and tail pointers*?

Comment: Rather than fiddle with swapping things, how about adding functions `enqueueFront`, `enqueueBack`, `dequeueFront`, and `dequeueBack`? The doubly-linked list becomes a [Double-ended queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) (also known as a deque).

Answer (score 2):

if you want to treat a doubly linked list as a queue, then it's only by convention which is the head and which is the tail by which way you want to iterate it.  But the point of a queue is it's interface.... so given any arbitrary queue, implemented in an unknown way  ( there are MANY things that implement queues, including queues that distribute themselves across many computers ) the question is, how can you you reverse it, and that means you cannot rely on an underlying implementation.

A specific implementation might implement optimizations for certain operations.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer : **NO**

**LONG ANSWER/REASON**

The queue is an abstract data type. That means there is no physical existence of such a data structure. A queue can be implemented in many ways. The most basic implementation is the one that uses arrays.

```
struct Queue{
 int elements[50];//The actual/physical (array)data structure which houses the data
 int max=50;//The maximum no of elements that can be stored in this queue.
 int front,rear;//pointers to the front and rear.
};
```

Now, I am sure you know how to define operations on this kind of a Queue.

```
void enQ(Queue &Q,int new_element);
int deQ(Queue &Q);
int getFront(Queue Q);
```

That means if I have to add an element `7` to the queue identified by `Q`, I need to execute `enQ(Q,7)`. Let us say I have added 10 items like that by calling `enQ` 10 times. Then I add a number `89` to the queue. Now if I have to get this number 89(assume that all numbers are unique), I will first have to `deQ` the first 10 items and the call the `deQ` function again to get 89. I am sure you will agree, that is the principle of a queue.

Now time for some magic. If I knew that 89 is the 11th number I added, I can get it directly by `Q.elements[(Q.front+11)%Q.max]`. Also if I knew that 89 is the number I just added, I can also get it by using `Q.elements[Q.rear]`.

Wow! Does that mean that the principles of the queue got violated? No. It just means that I am not using a queue anymore. I am actually using an array, but trying to fool myself, by doing it in a sophisticated manner(by putting it in a structure and all that).

If you are using a queue, You can only use the three methods I mentioned above. You are not allowed to meddle with the inner workings of the Queue. You might be thinking that your case is different because you are just wanting to change the front and rear values and not the actual data. But No. In a real queue, you are not even allowed to access the front and rear. All you have access to are the three methods I defined above.

That is why the actual implementation of a queue should be

```
class Queue{
   int elements[50];//The actual/physical (array)data structure which houses the data
   int max=50;//The maximum no of elements that can be stored in this queue.
   int front,rear;//pointers to the front and rear.

   public:

   void enQ(int new_element);
   int deQ();
   int getFront();
};
```

Now we are upholding the real essence of a Queue. A similar layout should be used if you are implementing a queue using a Doubly-linked-list. The front and rear pointers should be private and inaccessible to the user.

Therefore it is not possible to reverse a **QUEUE** faster than O(n).

So the bottom line is: If you want to change the queue pointers, by using a doubly-linked list, by all means you can do it. But you cannot call it reversing a queue. Because, then you would not be using a queue. In fact, that would be a completely new data structure called [DEQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). If you really want to implement reversing a queue in O(1) time complexity, I suggest you go ahead with your method. But you will have to stop calling it a queue because that is a DEQ(BTW, there is nothing wrong with using a DEQ, by all means, use it). Or if you don't like the sounding of a DEQ, you can define your own data structure called reversible queue.

You can define your data structure like

```
class ReversibleQueue{
   DLL front,rear; //pointers to a DOUBLY-LINKED-LIST

   public:

   void enQ(int new_element);
   int deQ();
   int getFront();
   void reverse();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot just swap the head and tail pointers of a doubly linked list. You also need to swap the next and previous pointers in each node. This will still take O(n) time.

Comment: That will not be a problem because he can have a flag determining which is front and which is back, and using that he can modify his algorithm conditionally. More specifically, instead of prev and next, he can have `DLL[2]`, and have two global `int` variables `prev=0` and `next=1`. While swapping the `front` and `rear` he can just swap the `prev` and `next` also. But that is not the point. The point is if he is meddling with the inner workings of the physical data structure, then it is no more a queue.

Comment: As Chavali mentioned, we can easily have a flag that determines which direction to go. If queue is not empty and `head.next` points to none then start using `head.prev`

Comment: @Beginner If you're going to use a flag, then why swap the `head` and `tail` pointers? Just set the `reverse` flag and be done with it. No pointer swapping required. Also remember that if you reverse the queue, you have to change which end the enqueue and dequeue functions affect.

Comment: @JimMischel "you have to change which end the enqueue and dequeue functions affect." Which is the problem swapping the head and tail pointers is trying to solve. There are also other ways to do it long the lines of VSS CHAITANYA Chavali's comment above.

Comment: The point is that you don't have to swap anything. Just put a `if (reversed)` in the code. You don't need to swap head or tail pointers, and you don't need to swap any pointers in the nodes.